# Downloading Existing Github Issues in Eclipse/Mylyn

Tags: eclipse, github, mylyn

I've connected my Eclipse to my Github repos via http://eclipse.github.com/ . I'm trying to get the issue tracking integration working. It seems I'm able to create new issues within Eclipse; I see them posted to Github. But what I can't seem to figure out is how to download all the issues I've previously created directly on Github, nor can I find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create 'queries'. In your *Task List* view (the Mylyn task list), use the menu to create a query. Choose your repository, and selection criteria (i.e. show tasks with a certain milestone or tag).  I actually wrote a short tutorial about this whole topic [here](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/08/28/tips-and-tricks-using-eclipse-with-github/).

Comment: I think you just saved me a lot of time digging. Thanks very much.